# Cant figure out stacking order issue on Chrome

Tags: css, z-index

My collapsed dropdown menus are being hidden behind a sequence.js slider on Chrome and Safari.  Issue doesn't appear to be happening on Firefox.  Tried changing z-index on just about every object related to slider and menu.  Much love to anyone who can inspect my site and tell me what I am doing wrong.

https://www.shopinspired.co/

Comment: This isn't the fix you're looking for, but in the mean time you can add `background: transparent` to `.seq-content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not actually being hidden behind the slideshow.

This is due to the "sticky" class being removed from your header when you scroll to the top of the page.  If #header always has .sticky, the menu shows fine.

It looks like your styles at the top of the page are targeting "header.sticky", not just "header".

Fix: Manually add the css:

```
#header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px #333;
}
```

or change the CSS in the page head to target "header".

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

Its is coming from the `sticky` header and a mismatch of positioned objects and forced heights.

By default, without the sticky header, the submenu is being hidden because it is a child element of a parent with a forced height due to some media queries. The overflow is being hidden.

When the `sticky` header is added, the header gets a position of `fixed`. You can not use `absolute` positioning relative to `fixed elements`. I am guessing your element is being positioned relative to the document window which is why it is now showing with the `fixed` attribute.